# Disable file permision

Tags: wireshark

I'm currently want to upload my file.pcap that I create from wireshark, but I cannot that upload that file to internet because file permision.

How can I disable permision? so that there is no x and lock icon like this?

Here's the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***How to Fix***

Changing Permissions.

- Right click on the file
- Go to `Permissions` tab
- Under all `Access` entries, choose `Read and Write`

***If that doesn't Work***

Launch your file manager as Super User.

- Type in a Terminal `sudo nautilus`
- Assuming you are using Nautilus as your file manager, if this doesn't work, try `sudo dolphin`

Change Permissions.

- Navigate to the `Permissions` tab
- Under all of the `Access` entries, click `Read and Write`

There you have it!  Good Luck!